# Анализ массива

Tags: c++

> Задан массив из k чисел. Определить количество инверсий в массиве  (т. е. таких пар элементов, в которых большее число находится слева от меньше-го).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задаете переменную-счетчик, обнуляете ее. Далее циклом  просматриваете массив (i меняется от 0 до k-2), сравниваете переменные i и i+1. Если array[i] > array [i+1], увеличиваете счетчик на 1.